# Is it possible in SQlite3 python that if a row has been previously updated, it cannot be updated for like 5 seconds

Tags: python, database, sqlite, sqlite3-python

In a database table, if a specific row has been previously modified or updated, I want that row to not be changed or cannot be modified for let's say I set in 5 seconds even if the program is trying to modify that row, then after that the row can be modified or update again. Is that possible?

I didn't try anything yet because I dont have an idea if it is possible or not

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is possible. To implement this kind of behaviour you can add a new column to your table let's call it `last_modified`. Which get's a default value of the current timestamp

```sql
CREATE TABLE your_table (
    ...
    last_modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

or

```sql
ALTER TABLE your_table ADD COLUMN last_modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Now each time you want to update your table you check if the affected row has been updated in the last 5 seconds if not update the row if yes throw an error.

```py
import sqlite3
import time

# Connect to the SQLite database
conn = sqlite3.connect('your_database.db')
cursor = conn.cursor()

# Create the table if it doesn't exist
cursor.execute('''CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS your_table
                  (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
                   column1 TEXT,
                   column2 TEXT,
                   last_modified TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)''')

# Function to check if a row can be modified
def can_modify_row(row_id, interval):
    cursor.execute("SELECT ROUND((JULIANDAY('now') - JULIANDAY(last_modified)) * 86400) FROM your_table WHERE id = ?", (row_id,))
    elapsed_time = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    return elapsed_time > interval

# Update a row, setting the last_modified timestamp to the current time
def update_row(row_id, column1_value, column2_value):
    cursor.execute("UPDATE your_table SET column1 = ?, column2 = ?, last_modified = CURRENT_TIMESTAMP WHERE id = ?", (column1_value, column2_value, row_id))
    conn.commit()

# Example usage
row_id = 1
interval = 5  # seconds

if can_modify_row(row_id, interval):
    print("Modifying the row...")
    update_row(row_id, "new_value1", "new_value2")
else:
    print("Cannot modify the row yet. Please try again later.")

# Close the database connection
conn.close()
```

The code is currently untested, but I hope  you get the idea

Comment: Thank you for your response and the idea, I will try this now

Comment: The return elapsed_time > interval is causing error

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\mike\Desktop\import sqlite3.py", line 32, in <module>
    if can_modify_row(row_id, interval):
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "c:\Users\mike\Desktop\import sqlite3.py", line 19, in can_modify_row
    return elapsed_time > interval
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: '>' not supported between instances of 'list' and 'int'

Comment: @Shinshiiin Since you accepted my answer I assume you fixed the error?! Can you tell what was wrong?